# Play m3u8 file in react native

Tags: react-native

Will react native video player will play m3u8 HLS format during live streaming and also file from within the app
Its working fine in offline but If we try to play the downloaded file its not working.

Comment: You will be more likely to receive helpful answers if you provide some more details, which video player package for instance, and add a code example outlining what you already tried.